# For some reason I can't open files on drive

Tags: hard-drive, uti, ntfs

I can't open the files on certain drive that is formatted as ntfs. I have Tuxera installed however. Here is an image on how they look:

The file with a lock is password protected as it should.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this? For some reason the files I can't open are somehow transparent.

Comment: What are the permissions of the file you are trying to access. Do a Get Info on the file.

Comment: I can read and write.... I should be able to access them... :(

Comment: What are the permissions on the file if you do, in Termiinal, ls -ls ?

Comment: These: -rwxrwxrwx@ 1 JLD  staff  983217 Sep 18 13:48 NoPassLibro.pdf What do you think?

Comment: Your problem is the '@'. This means that you have extended attributes set on the file. Do a ls -l@ to see what extended attribute it is

Comment: this is it: -rwxrwxrwx@ 1 JLD  staff  983217 Sep 18 13:48 NoPassLibro.pdf
 com.apple.FinderInfo     32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, make sure that it's no locked and that you have the correct permissions :
[image]

If you have extended attributes you can get rid of those by doing the following :

1- Do `ls -l@`, under the file it will give you something like "com.apple.FinderInfo". Copy that
2- Do `xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo path/to/file`

If nothing works then your last option is to sudo it :
`sudo open path/to/file`

Also see if you can open it using a mac that those not have Tuxera installed on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A `xattr -dr com.apple.FinderInfo nameOfTheDrive` did the trick.